# JavaScript onScroll event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, scroll, preventdefault

Is there any way to use `preventDefault` on scroll event? Container must have `overflow-y: scroll`. I wouldn't like to use `mousewheel` `preventDefault`, because then I would have to write solution for mouse, keyboard, touch displays and scrollbar.

So, how to disable scrolling in `<div>` below? ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kv61t1nm/))

```js
document.getElementById('container').onscroll = function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
};
```

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scrollTo()` on the specific element and the set its scroll to the previous position. Assuming that the original position is `(0,0)`, you can use that. If, however, it changes somehow, you will need to extend the logic to accommodate for that change. Bear in mind that there is a slight scrolling hiccup that is visible when the user tries to scroll.

#### Working demo

```js
document.getElementById('container').onscroll = function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById('container').scrollTo(0,0);
};
```

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

**Note:** I strongly recommend against this, as intercepting scroll events can cause a lot of trouble with usability of your page, but if you are sure about it, you do what you must!